# How do I solve two equations in two unknowns?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In my free time, I've been challenging my mind with IQ problems. I found this question:

> Jim has as many sisters as he has brothers,
>       but his sister has twice as many brothers as she has sisters.
>       How many boys and how many girls are there in the family?

I figured out that the answer is that there are 4 boys and 3 girls in the family. This is totally guessing though. I see many math problems like this with practice IQ questions and I'm trying to find a logical way to work these out on paper. With these problems, I'll figure out two math equations and then just insert numbers into them until I figure it out which doesn't seem like the right way to do it. For example, with this one I had (where $G$ is girl and $B$ is boy):

$$G = B - 1$$ (Because Jim would be one of the boys in the first condtion)
and
$$(G - 1)\times2 = B$$ (Because the sister would be one of the girls and then she had twice as many)

How do I do a comparison between two math problems? I'm obviously no math genius but I figured I'd reach out for help than try to search for an answer in my head that I don't believe I'll know :) Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $B$ be the number of boys, and $G$ the number of girls.

First statement says that $B-1=G$, or $B=G+1$

Second one says that $G-1=B/2$, or $B=2G-2$

$G+1=2G-2$ implies that $G=3$, and of course $B=4$.

EDIT: changed variables names to fit with question.

Comment: Ah of course, you compare the same variable against itself. It's obviously been a while since algebra for me :/ I'll accept your answer when they let me. Thanks!

Comment: You might have used the $B$ and $G$ variables the OP used in the question, rather than $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm You are right, I will edit the answer.

Comment: G for boys and B for girls? o.O

Comment: Corrected - again!

Comment: Recall that the *Transitive Axiom of Equality* says that
$$
\text{if }a=b\text{ and }b=c\text{ then }a=c
$$

You apply this axiom in your problem as follows
$$\text{if }G+1=B\text{ and }B=2G-2\text{ then }G+1=2G-2$$